# Posición vertical de un elemento soltado con Drag and Drop (jquery UI)

Tags: jquery-ui

Buenas!!! Estoy tratando de hacer un sistema el cual te permita ordenar el contenido mediante el Drag and Drop de Jquery UI, estas posiciones tengo que guardarlas en la base de datos para que cuando el usuario vuelva a loguear en el sistema el entorno siga teniendo el mismo orden que él le dio en su momento.
La posición horizontal del elemento la guardo perfectamente puesto que al soltarlo directamente upgradeo el padre, pero cuando quiero guardar la posición vertical (no necesito el top sino el número de elementos que tiene por encima), no soy capaz de hacer que me devuelva el número correcto en todas las situaciones que se pueden dar.

He intentado dos formas de hacerlo:

```
       $(".col-lg-3").droppable({
            greedy: true,
            classes: {
                "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-active",
                "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover",
            },
            drop: function(event, ui){

                var topPosition = ui.draggable.position().top;

                var taskId = ui.draggable.data('task');
                var parentId = $(this).attr('id');

                var posicion = 0;

                $(this).children('.taskRecipient').each(function(){


                    if($(this).position().top < topPosition)
                    {
                        console.log($(this).position().top + " : " + topPosition);
                        posicion++;
                    }

                });

                console.log(posicion);

                $.ajax({
                    url: base_url + 'Task/changeTaskParent',
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        'parent'    : parentId,
                        'taskId'    : taskId
                    },
                    success: function(){
                    },
                    error: function(){
                    }
                });

                posicion = 0;
            },
        });
```

El problema que tiene esta forma es que me cuenta el elemento tanto en el origen como al final del drop, es decir si cambio de columna padre me devuelve el valor correcto pero si lo hago dentro de la columna siempre me devuelve un numero más.

La primera forma que intente fue directamente añadir una clase "soltado", contar los elementos de la columna padre hasta que encontrase un elemento que tuviese esa clase y me devolviera el valor, Esta forma funciona perfectamente si lo muevo dentro de la misma columna padre pero si cambio de columna me devuelve el número de elementos completos de la columna mas uno indiferentemente en la posición que lo suelte.

Se que es un tema complicado y difícil de explicar, toda ayuda será bienvenida